# Exclude word in match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm making email addresses clickable with this code:

```
function makeemail($str) {

   $str = preg_replace('/([\!~#$%&=?^*\/_\.\+0-9a-zæøå-]+)@(([0-9a-zæøå-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,12})/i', '<a href="mailto:$1@$2" title="">$1@$2</a>', $str);

   return trim($str);

}
```

**What can I do so it ignores text where "http://" and "https://" is part of it?** (or maybe just "http", to be simple)

Some http server url's can have @ in the address, and I'm dealing with http url's in an other function.

I'm a bit of a regex noob. I tried adding `?!http:\/\/` or `?!https?:\/\/` with and without parantheses, but it doesn't work and it's out of my scope where/how to put it exactly.

---

`emailaddress@example.com` - this should become `<a href="mailto:email@address.com" title="">email@address.com</a>` (which it does perfectly)

`http://userid:password@example.com:8080/` - this should be ignored and leaved as is because it contains `http(s)://`)

Comment: Use the negative lookahead properly: `(?!.*?https?:\/\/)`. It should be at the beginning. Still we should see some samples of input string.

Comment: Please provide some examples and expected results.

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/BDWy5n/1/ or https://regex101.com/r/BDWy5n/2/ depending on how your strings are written

Comment: @revo Inside or outside the first inner paranthesis and without any other changes to the code? I tried both places, but they both makes the code ignore any regular (without http) email addresses too

Comment: Now it is clear. Forget about lookahead and put `https?:\/\/\S+(*SKIP)(*F)|` at beginning of your current regex. See this https://regex101.com/r/ZsdYSS/1

Comment: @revo that seems to work well :) Thank you. Never seen SKIP etc. before. Add an answer with a brief explanation maybe?